# Ethereum node stuck can't sync. for Win. 8.1

Tags: wallets, synchronization, nodes, peers

I've downloaded the latest Win. version but can't make the Ethereum node sync. I've also turned my firewall off but still not working. Can anyone help? I'm not a techie guy. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What does `eth.syncing` command show?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a corrupt blockchain, in which case, you can open windows explorer and manually type into the address bar: `%appdata%`. Then go to the `/Ethereum` folder and delete or remane the `/chaindata` folder. This will force the wallet to resync the blockchain from the genesis. Note that any existing wallets will be saved.